# Changing JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a `JSON` object of

```
[ 
  { serial: 5456454, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 563535434, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 576757575, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 785785758, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 2147483647, 'COUNT(*)': 8 } 
]
```

And my requirement is to change/convert this as

```
[ 
  { serial: 5456454, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 563535434, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 576757575, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 785785758, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 2147483647, count: 8 } 
]
```

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: You should probably just decode the JSON in some language and loop through the array and just switch each 'COUNT(*)' to 'count' instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **MAP** from EcmaScript 5 to do that things

```
var a = [ 
{ serial: 5456454, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 563535434, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 576757575, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 785785758, 'COUNT(*)': 1 }, 
  { serial: 2147483647, 'COUNT(*)': 8 } 
];

a = a.map(function(t){
    return {serial: t.serial, count: t["COUNT(*)"]};
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: I got like this `[Object { serial=5456454, count=12}, Object { serial=563535434, count=4}, Object { serial=576757575, count=4}, Object { serial=785785758, count=4}, Object { serial=2147483647, count=8}]`

Comment: I want like this `[ 
  { serial: 5456454, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 563535434, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 576757575, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 785785758, count: 1 }, 
  { serial: 2147483647, count: 8 } 
]`

Comment: @user2625250 what language do you use?

Comment: @user2625250 how you get [Object { serial=5456454, count=12} ... it is impossible in javascript

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48452/discussion-between-user2625250-and-fuserthrowerror)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `forEach` method(or loop through the array, if you want to support IE):

```
json.forEach(function (e) {
    e.count = e['COUNT(*)'];
    delete e['COUNT(*)'];
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/SNVz4/)

Comment: I got like this `[Object { serial=5456454, count=12}, Object { serial=563535434, count=4}, Object { serial=576757575, count=4}, Object { serial=785785758, count=4}, Object { serial=2147483647, count=8}]`

Comment: @user2625250 Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

[@tewathia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22036717/940252) is spot on.

If you need to support IE 8 or earlier, use this instead:

```
for(var i = 0, l = json.length; i < l; i++) {
    json[i].count = json[i]['COUNT(*)'];
    delete json[i]['COUNT(*)'];
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6X43d/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the array and create a new object with the desired properties. Also note you can't reference the 'COUNT(*)' property directly

```
var newJsonArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    var obj = jsonArray[i];
    var newObj = {};
    newObj.serial = obj['serial'];
    newObj.count = obj['COUNT(*)'];
    newJsonArray.push(newObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code and the fiddle below:

code:

```
var b= [];
for(var i = 0;i<a.length-1;i++){
    var bElement = {};
    bElement.serial = a[i].serial;
    bElement.count = a[i]["COUNT(*)"];
    b.push(bElement);
}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Wjn3/